# get last record of a table in database?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2008

i am developing a project and after the user insert the data of the customer he suppose to print the ID and the name of the Customer , 
this is the code of the ID

```
int getPatnID()
    {
        int ID = (from i in Db.Patients
                  select i.patn_ID).Max();
        return ID;
    }
```

i have write the code to get the name but i cant finish it

```
string getPatnName()
    {
        string name = (from n in Db.Patients
                       select n.patn_name).

        return name;
    }
```

How should i write to complete it ??

Comment: Just a warning...if there are multiple clients operating against the DB, grabbing the last record after an insert is dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `getPatnName` to take an id:

```
string getPatnName(int id)
{
    string name = (from n in Db.Patients
                   where n.patn_ID == id
                   select n.patn_name).SingleOrDefault();

    return name;
}
```

and give it the result of `getPatnID()`

Comment: I have never seen the where after the select.  Will that work in Linq?

Comment: there is where after select and also there is join :) , powerful Library ;)

Answer (score 4):

This should always get the last inserted record at time of execution (assuming patn_id is auto-incrementing)

```
string GetPatnName() 
{
    string name = (from n in Db.Patients 
                   orderby n.patn_ID descending 
                   select n.patn_name).FirstOrDefault();
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string getPatnName() {
    string name = Db.Patients.Last(p => p.patn_ID).patn_name;
    return name;
}
```

I suggest you spend some more time studying LINQ - it is a very rich and powerful library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx

Comment: The query operator 'Last' is not supported.  i got this error when i use this

Comment: Sorry about that mistake, I didn't realize that the OR/M you are using does not support the Last operator. Try it with the updated code. Basically what it is doing is selecting the last element that matches the predicate that you specify - in this case, the ID of each individual patient record.

Comment: i tried to use last before but it doesnot work , but thanks for the Advice and yah i think it is a very powerful library

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the name of the last patient you just entered, and you have the ID from the first query, you just need a where clause in your LINQ.

```
string name = (from n in Db.Patients
       where n.patn_ID == ID
       select n.patn_name);
```

Comment: beware my comment in your question.  Getting the ID by reading the last record is okay if you only have a single client running against the DB.  Otherwise you'll need to rethink the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the id the way you do is wrong. Not sure what you're using, but both linq-2-sql and entity framework fill in the entity Id when saving changes:

```
    Patient patient = new Patient();
    Console.WriteLine(patient.Id); // will NOT be filled in
    Db.Patients.Add(patient);
    Db.SubmitChanges(); // SaveChanges in EF
    Console.WriteLine(patient.Id); // will be filled in
```

Comment: i don think it is wrong as it already work , and get the right result

Comment: That is by accident. Like @ncydan already mentioned, in a multi-user scenario this is guaranteed to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a patient class an return an instance as shown below

```
public class Patient
{
    public int PatientID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


static Patient getDetails()
    {
        using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var c = (from x in db.Patients.OrderByDescending(u => u.PatientID)
                     select new Patient()
                     {
                         PatientID = x.PatientID,
                         Name = x.Name
                     }).FirstOrDefault();
            return c;
        }
```

Comment: isn't it too long to get an ID and Name for 1 use ??

Comment: sorry you're right I didn't read the question correctly & just thought that all that was required was a means of getting the last value from a table